# Function into simulation?

Tags: r

I built this function to simulate a craps game and count the number of wins and losses.

```
craps <- function(x) 
  {
  firstroll <- sum(floor(runif(1,1,6)),floor(runif(1,1,6)))
}
  if (firstroll == 7 | firstroll == 11) 
  {
    NumWins = NumWins + 1
    } else if (firstroll == 2 | firstroll == 3 | firstroll == 12) 
    {
    NumLoss = NumLoss + 1 
  } else 
    {
    diceroll <- sum(floor(runif(1,1,6)),floor(runif(1,1,6)))
    while (dice_roll != firstroll && dice_roll != 7)
    {
      diceroll <- sum(floor(runif(1,1,6)),floor(runif(1,1,6)))
    }
    if (diceroll == firstroll) 
    {
      NumWins = NumWins + 1
    }
    else 
    {
      NumLoss = NumLoss + 1 
    }
}
```

Where should I put the X for the function?

Like this?

```
firstroll <- sum(floor(runif(x,1,6)),floor(runif(x,1,6)))
```

But when I put x here I get sum's of the rolls into the 1ks

My ultimate goal is to build a simulation were I can run x amount of time to see the number of wins, losses and total tosses

Comment: Theres an issue in your code relating to how you sample your numbers, see my answer below (upvote and accept if answers solve your question please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
craps <- function(x) {
  one_game <- function() {
    firstroll <- sum(sample.int(6L, 2L, TRUE))
    tosses <- 1L
    if (firstroll %in% c(7L, 11L)) {
      return(c(win = 1L, loss = 0L, tosses = 1L))
    }
    if (firstroll %in% c(2L, 3L, 12L)) {
      return(c(win = 0L, loss = 1L, tosses = 1L))
    }
    repeat {
      tosses <- tosses + 1L
      roll <- sum(sample.int(6L, 2L, TRUE))
      if (roll == firstroll) {
        return(c(win = 1L, loss = 0L, tosses = tosses))
      }
      if (roll == 7L) {
        return(c(win = 0L, loss = 1L, tosses = tosses))
      }
    }
  }
  rowSums(replicate(x, one_game()))
}
```

Output:

```
> craps(10)
   win   loss tosses 
     4      6     29 
> craps(100)
   win   loss tosses 
    57     43    338 
> craps(1000)
   win   loss tosses 
   514    486   3285 
> craps(10000)
   win   loss tosses 
  4888   5112  33719 
> craps(100000)
   win   loss tosses 
 49323  50677 337467
```

Comment: Thanks a lot did you have that ready to go or wrote from scratch.

Comment: I wrote that from scratch. @CQtiandi

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to put this into a monte carlo simulation? @ekoam

Comment: @CQtiandi Isn't this already a Monte Carlo simulation? This is what you get after playing craps n times. Or maybe you want to simulate the result after repeating m times the n-time craps game?

Comment: What I want to do is stop the simulation after a win or a loss. And count how many tosses it took to get to either outcome. So 1 win, 0 loss, 5 tosses. Would be the outcome. @ekoam

Comment: Then I want to run that 10k times and find the avg number of wins and the avg number of tosses to get those wins. @ekoam

Comment: Yes, this simulation gives exactly what you want. You just need to do this `craps(10000) / 10000` @CQtiandi

Answer (score 0):

I'd take this sort of route - you will have to check this as I am unfamiliar with the rules of craps, but a simple `sapply()` with a vector of 1 to `x`. Note I've used `sample()` -  `floor(runif(1, 1, 6))` will never return a 6 - and `%in%`:

```
craps <- function(x) {
  # Will create a vector of 'W's and 'L's for wins and losses
  results <- sapply(1:x, function(i){
    # First roll of the dice
    firstroll <- sum(sample(c(1:6), size = 2, replace = TRUE))
    # Check total
    if(firstroll %in% c(7, 11)){
      return('W')
    }
    if(firstroll %in% c(2, 3, 12)){
      return('L')
    }
    # Second roll
    else {
      secondroll <- sum(sample(c(1:6), size = 2, replace = TRUE))
      if(secondroll == firstroll){
        return('W')
      }
      else {
        return('L')
      }
    }
  })
  # Return a table of win and loss counts
  table(results)
}

craps(25000)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your implementation only allows two rolls for each game? I think he needs something that can keep running as long as the `sum` is not equal to 7 or the `sum` on the first roll.